# How to transform a normalized number where .75 is ideal, not 1

Tags: normalization, logistic-regression

In a training/deploying a simple logistic regression, one of the variables is designed such that it can take on normalized values between 0 and 1. The problem is that .75 is the ideal value.

Is there way to 'transform' this such that .75 is transformed to equal 1 and every other number close to it is perhaps given a number lower to 1 dependent on how far it is from .75?

Thanks!
Will

Comment: what do you mean by ideal value?

Comment: the value at which I would like a trained logistic regression would output the highest probability. I was under the impression that logistic regressions put higher value on higher input numbers.

Comment: 1-((0.75 -X)/0.75)

Comment: 1-(|0.75 -X|)/0.75) ?

Answer (score 0):

Given X your current variable, use:
1-[(0.75 -X)/0.75]
or shorter:
[X/0.75]

Comment: 1-[(|0.75 -X|)/0.75] may work, however this assumes a linear relationship as you get farther from .75. I am probably okay with this for my application but I am curious if there is a common method for, for example, normalizing a kernel density estimate with supports at 0 and 1 and with a peak at 0.75 and using that as a transformation.